# How often do 0-0 scores at the completion of regulation occur in major sports?

Tags: statistics

Have been watching hockey a bit more recently and tonight's game didn't have a lot of scoring early on.  That got me wondering how often the dreaded 0-0 scoreline comes up in different sports (defensive struggles aren't so bad, but I've certainly heard disparaging nicknames for them!).

Specifically, I am thinking of soccer, hockey, baseball, and (American) football as the four team sports where 0-0 seems fairly feasible.  I suppose there are a few others like lacrosse and water polo.

Whether they have overtime, shootouts, or draws, I'm just interested in how often they complete regulation 0-0 (though statistics on how often extended time also ends 0-0 aren't discouraged).

Comment: Here are some stats from EPL: [In 126 Years, English Football Has Seen 13,475 Nil-Nil Draws](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/in-126-years-english-football-has-seen-13475-nil-nil-draws/).

Comment: Great!  Sounds quite near being a good answer to me if you gave a few of the salient points.  I expect there may well be separate answers for each sport, since different people know the sources for such information (if they're even easy to get)?  I appreciate you digging that up!

Comment: There was not much digging involved. All I did was to enter [nil nil draw statistics](https://www.google.com/search?q=nil+nil+draw+statistics) into Google. If you really think that this might be a start for an answer about football part, feel free to make an answer out of it. (Perhaps making it [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) might be a good idea, if you want other users to contribute to the answer.)

Comment: Both rugby variants (union and league) occasionally have 0-0 draws as well.

Comment: When you say "major sports," do you mean "most popular" sports or "professional" sports? I ask because of a current [meta discussion](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/776) being discussed in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37597470#37597470).

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ Great to see there's such discussion, as I was at a loss how to tag it!  I was definitely hopeful to go a bit beyond major 4, at least into soccer, and hopeful to see a few others in the comparison too.  The inclusion of the phrase was more to prevent it from being wildly open-ended (indeed, no interest in tiddly winks or middle school football stats) and getting ire/deflecting it from the main interest subjects.  I'll certainly weigh in on the tags, as I think they'd be useful!

Answer (score 10):

In the **NHL**, there have been **[41 games tied 0-0](http://www.hockey-reference.com/play-index/tiny.fcgi?id=77ibJ) after overtime since the introduction of the shootout** in 2005 (meaning they would have been recorded as a 0-0 tie in the past), which is **[0.25%](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=41%2F(13*(30*82)%2F2))** of games.  And there have been **[189 0-0 ties](http://www.hockey-reference.com/play-index/tiny.fcgi?id=QzKQr)** in history (dating back to 1924) [games are double-counted in link]. There have been **[122 games that were 0-0](http://www.hockey-reference.com/play-index/tiny.fcgi?id=GJZvP) after regulation only to be ended in overtime (not a shootout)**. This gives **352 total 0-0 games after regulation.** Note that this is just regular season, and not playoffs.

In the **NFL**, there have only been **[two 0-0 games](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tiny.fcgi?id=KwKkC)** [games are double-counted in link]. The last one occurred in 1943. I couldn't find [any other games](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tiny.fcgi?id=HMIpv) that went into overtime tied 0-0 (checked each box score individually), either, which surprises me. Those 0-0 ties were Detroit against the Chicago Cardinals, and Detroit again against the NY Giants.

For the **MLB**, I was able to find **[at least 620 games that were tied 0-0](https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/tiny.fcgi?id=oV8n6) after 9 innings** by looking up games where that took extra innings and the losing team had 0 runs. There appear to be a handful every year by changing the dates. I am not a subscriber, so I cannot verify the total or see more games.  This also does not take into account games that were tied 0-0 after 9 innings where the losing team managed at least 1 runs, so there are more.

In the top 4 tiers of **English soccer**, from 1888 through 2014, **[13,475 games (7.2% of matches) ended 0-0](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/in-126-years-english-football-has-seen-13475-nil-nil-draws/)**.

Seems like it's nearly impossible in the **NFL**, not too uncommon in the **NHL**, very common in the **MLB**, and almost weekly in English soccer.

Comment: for soccer the answer just will be too long.. is not unusual...

Comment: An important point is that baseball can't end with a tie while the other sports can. So while it may be common to have 0-0 after 9, the game never ends that way.  And I wouldn't consider a handful common. There are about 2,430 baseball games in one year.